# Single Page Application - GTM script add duplicate script blocks for every page visit

Tags: google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

Our website primarily has a Single Page Application (SPA) behaviour. We use Google Tag Manager to deploy all our tags and makes use of the History API in some cases to detect a scenario such as an URL change etc.

Recently, we noticed that as a user navigates through pages the following happens:

Example with Google Ads Double Click script:

User lands on Page A - GTM dynamically load the Double Click script (expected behaviour).

User clicks on a tile and goes to Page B - GTM dynamically loads Double Click script. However, the previous Double Click script (from Page A) is also still there.

User goes to Page C - GTM dynamically loads Double Click script. However, the previous Double Click scripts (from Page A and B) are also still there.

As a result, the webpage size grows due to multiple scripts and we are experiencing a big memory leak, the more time the user spends on our website.

This happens with all scripts that are supposed to fire on a particular page.

How can we avoid this memory leak from happening? Greatly appreciate all the support anyone can provide.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem with third party scripts that get injected in DOM. I'm having a look to https://partytown.builder.io/ in case it will work for our problem and also improve our overall page performance.